# how to parse using Jsonpath?

Tags: jsonpath

I want to know the value of 'pageName' where the value of 'createdTs' is '333' in JSON like below, how should I use Jsonpath?

```
[
   {
      "Test1":{
         "pageName":"Apple"
        },
         "Test1-1":{
            "createdTs":"333"
        }
    },
   {
      "Test2":{
         "pageName":"Tomato"
        },
         "Test2-1":{
            "createdTs":"555"
        }
    }
]
```

`.Test1-1[?(@.createdTs == 333)]` would look like this:

```
[
   {
      "createdTs" : "333"
   }
]
```

The parsing result I want is this.

```
[
   {
      "Test1":{
         "pageName":"Apple"
        },
         "Test1-1":{
            "createdTs":"333"
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using [Jayway JSONPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#jayway-jsonpath) a Java DSL for reading JSON documents, then you can use the these jsonpath expressions.

```
$[?(@.['Test1-1'].createdTs == 333)]
```

**OR** using in filter operator

```
$[?(333 in @..createdTs)]
```

**OR** using contains filter operator

```
$[?(@..createdTs contains 333)]
```

Comment: All 3 methods work fine. Thank you very much.

Comment: By any chance, how can I filter only those higher than 444, not 'contain'?

I shouldn't do it like this
$[?(@..createdTs > 444)]

Comment: Please confirm https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70092422/please-tell-me-how-to-parse-with-jsonpath